# validating an array of regex string on a string

Tags: python, regex, django

I have an array of regex to apply on a string.

```
regexString = "'\d{2,}';'..'"
regexPatterns = regexString.split(";")
regexPatterns = ["'\d{2,}'","'..'"]
```

How can I efficiently use that list and only match if all the regex find a match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the built-in [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) function:

```
isgood = all(re.search(regex, s) for regex in regexPatterns)
```